# How to load a apache solr document and send it for reindex after editing is done in drupal 7

Tags: 7, search

As title says,

I want to load a particular node's document and When the editing is done, I need to send the modified document to Solr for re-index programtically.

How it can be done?

Comment: Based on your question, I think you are approaching your actual problem from a wrong angle. I'm guessing what you're trying to do can be achieved with a different approach. Can you specify what you want to achieve by doing this? Because when you resave the node, the document will be overwritten in the index anyway; no need to download the old data for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the apachesolr module, nodes are automatically marked for reindexing after an edit.  So there is nothing you need to do.

If for some reason you need to manually mark a node, the code is

```
apachesolr_mark_entity('node', $nid);
```

Comment: Will it consider the re-indexing even if this node is in an unpublished state?